# ASP.NET MVC Validation of Script Tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to prevent a user from entering any `<script>` tags inside a textarea box I have called story using very similar code to this:

```
if (ArticleToCreate.story.Contains("<script>") == true)
                ModelState.AddModelError("Story", "No script tags allowed!");
```

Unfortunately this won't work because it's looking for `<script>` exactly as it is rather than looking for `<script>some code</script>` or some code`

Can anyone help? **I want to use very similar code to as shown above and not any Service Layers or Model scripts. Thanks**

Comment: Generally speaking trying to combat XSS attacks with your own rolled solution is rarely a good idea. A simple solution is to just HTML encode all user input (which you should be doing anyway and Razor does automatically for you).

Comment: I'm not looking for a secure solution just looking to check for these tags and then throw validation error if possible.

Answer (score 3):

By default, MVC won't allow this. If you explicitly allow it (e.g., with `[ValidateInput(false)]`), then you need to use a tool like the [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) to sanitize the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to allow users to enter some HTML but not any HTML, I recommend investigating the [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/), which includes methods for making user-entered HTML fragments "safe".

I agree with Matt Greer in saying that trying to create your own solution for recognizing illegal tags is a bad idea. There are so many attack vectors to inject script into HTML that you won't be able to guard against all of them. (See this [XSS Cheat Sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) for a sampling, but it's out of date so there are probably more.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use html encoding to obtain what you are looking for, something like this.

<%: model.story %> <---------that would help you, im assuming that you are using asp.net mvc 2 if not you can use something like this:

<%=Html.Encode(Model.story)%> <-----that's for asp.net mvc but that's for server side validation you can always add you own client side validation.