# How can I check for any html <script> tags in C#, plus anything else nasty?

Tags: c#, html, regex

A user is allowed to format their html in a textbox. This then gets sent to the backend where it will be validated. Other users may then see this textbox.

I want to check for any  tags in the backend. I know this can be done with a relatively simple regex. I would just do something like `<\s*?script\s*?>`

My issue though is if someone does something like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com" onClick="alert(1);">test</a>
```

This would pass validation. I could also make the regex check for onClick, but I'm sure there are other ways around this.

My question: Is there a good way to do this? Am I just going to have to rely on regexes and my own research to figure out how else they could run a script?

EDIT

I suppose I could create a whitelist of what they can enter. It's primarily meant for formatting text, so `<b>, <i>, <h>` etc. This may or may not be an acceptable solution though, I need to look and see what the actual use case is. I'm hoping there's a different solution to this.

Comment: Create an array of the JS functions then parse the HTML through a function to check for one of many 'blocked' keywords

Comment: Do you need the user to input _any_ html?

Comment: Not sure if this might be off topic for what you asked, but might be worth checking out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683907/asp-net-mvc-validation-of-script-tags  and http://wpl.codeplex.com/   It might still be relevent since you're dealing with JavaScript in HTML.

Comment: Stack Overflow solves this problem by asking users to type in Markdown. How about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really you should use white-list validation (i.e. allow only specific examples that you know are safe) rather than trying to detect and remove potentially hazardous input.

One really nice way to do this is to use Markdown rather than just allowing HTML input.

There are [OWASP Guidelines for HTML injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML_Injection).

Comment: I agree with the whitelist. Here is a C# library which may be useful for parsing HTML in order to clean it up: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: So I was thinking more about this. How would a whitelist work on attacks like <IMG SRC=javascript:alert('XSS')>. IMG and SRC would both be on the whitelist, so this would get through.

Answer (score -1):

A simple for removing all HTML tags from content

```
public string Strip(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, @”<(.|\n)*?>”, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to remove all HTML tags. Users should be able to make text bold, italic etc. I just don't want them to be able to execute a script.

Comment: then use this regex to remove javascript tags **"<script[^<]*</script>"**

Comment: I think this will help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223840/how-to-get-actual-javascript-value-in-onclick-from-webbrowser-control)